# How to read a text file line by line Windows RT?

Tags: c#, windows-8, io, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

i just cant find a clean explanation on how to read a text file, line by line in Windows RT ( for Windows 8 Store).

Lets say i have a folder: `MyFolder/Notes.txt`

And i want to read the data from Notes.txt and add it to an array of strings.

How do i read/write from that file? I was using StreamReader before, but now it is very confusing. And the dev samples dont help that much.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to Windows RT apps?

Comment: Should be the same as before.  You have any code written?  Can you show it?

Comment: Yes, Windows RT apps for the Windows 8 Store.

Comment: File I/O was majorly designed for WinRT.  Be sure to look at the File Access sample for guidance.  Scenario 2 shows you how to use FileIO.ReadTextAsync() to read a text file.  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ive managed to find the answer myself. Thanks for the help.

```
    // READ FILE
    public async void ReadFile()
    {
        // settings
        var path = @"MyFolder\MyFile.txt";
        var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;


        // acquire file
        var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
        var readFile = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
        foreach (var line in readFile)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("" + line.Split(';')[0]);
        }
     }
```

MyFile.txt has:

Test1;Description1;

Test2;Description2;

//Output for ReadFile()

Test1

Test2

Comment: good job, I asked a similar question recently and I ended up being downvoted many times, and 20 people edited my code, all disagreeing with each others edits

Comment: Well, `ReadLinesAsync` reads all the lines eagerly into the memory, which might be not what you want. (I failed to find a truly lazy way of reading text files with WinRT, like `File.ReadLines`.)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use `File.ReadLines`. You try an implementation like this if you prefer:

> ```
> using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("notes.txt"))
> {
>     while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: It seems that StreamReader is different in Windows RT. I was using your example before, but now they have changed it.

Comment: This code is successful on Windows 8 using the target framework .NET 3.5

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("MyFolder/Notes.txt"))
{
  ...
}
```

reads the file line by line. This is different from `File.ReadAllLines` which reads the entire file at once.

If you want to read everything at once, into an array, use the latter.