# Reading from file in a Windows RT Application

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read a text file line by line Windows RT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997464/how-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line-windows-rt)

I am trying to read from file line by line in C#.

This is my code

```
   String filename = "apoel.txt";

   System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
```

I followed instructions from an [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and followed them exactly. The problem is I keep getting the errors

> *The best overloaded method match for System.IO.StreamReader.StreamReader (System.IO.Stream)' has some
>   invalid arguments
>
>   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'*

I added `using System.IO`; on the top of my code

What am I doing wrong? If it is of any help this is a Windows Metro app

Also can someone explain to me why the article from MSDN that I post is wrong and not working? Do not give me an alternative please. Please tell me why my code is not working while it is explained like that in MSDN

Comment: You need to pass a `stream` to the `StreamReader()`.  You're passing `filename` which I can only assume is a `string` based upon the error.  More code would be helpful.

Comment: I removed the useless code from your post. Please try to only post relevant information.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders I did not include a tag I added the language...

Comment: @TyrionLannister I had code that included what filename was and Dave Zych removed it. Adding it back.

Comment: @JohnSaunders another person edited after you and added C# back. I hope all of you guys realize that all the edits you guys did altogether disagree with each other

Comment: @JohnDemetriou: take the time to read the FAQ. We're _supposed_ to edit your posts. So are you! The language is named "C#", not "CSharp", and that's the tag I removed.

Comment: FYI, you were also reading documentation from .NET 1.1 and Visual Studio 2003. Be very careful about that. The Internet is full of old and useless information. Note that the MSDN URL had "(v=vs.71)" in it. In most cases, when you remove that version part from the URL, you'll get a URL to the latest version.

Comment: thank you for being so helpful after someone else answered to that

Comment: LOL, people keep on editing and changing tags and title :P this questions had like 4 different versions..... after my original question. Total of 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code i use for Reading/Writing a file in Windows 8. It works and i hope it helps you too.

```
private StorageFolder localFolder;
// Read from a file line by line
public async Task ReadFile()
{
    try
    {
        // get the file
        StorageFile myStorageFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("MyDocument.txt");
        var readThis = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(myStorageFile);
        foreach (var line in readThis)
        {
            String myStringLine = line;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("File read successfully.");
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
    {   
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);           
    }
}
// Write to a file line by line
public async void SaveFile()
{
    try
    {
        // set storage file
        StorageFile myStorageFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("MyDocument.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        List<String> myDataLineList = new List<string>();
        await FileIO.WriteLinesAsync(myStorageFile, myDataLineList);
        Debug.WriteLine("File saved successfully.");
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
    {  
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You were reading documentation which didn't take into account the fact that many of the members of `StreamReader` aren't available in Windows Store apps.

Look at the overall [`StreamReader` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx). You can *only* use the members with a green bag next to them.

File access in Windows Store apps is a little different to full desktop .NET. I suggest you read this [MSDN guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx). Once you've got a `Stream`, you can build a `StreamReader` - or you could use the members of [`Windows.Storage.FileIO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.aspx) such as [`ReadLinesAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701475.aspx), depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you sir. Everyone else was giving me crap with no explanation. This is a proper answer.... They even removed my portions of my code which forced others to ask me for more code... This is a proper answer. Thank you sir. People keep trying to be smart around here. Removing stuff from questions. Editing stuff. Instead of simply posting answer. Btw your answer forced others to delete their answers :P Awesome job. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In the example that you post above filename is not initialized to anything. With a later version of the compiler it complains about unassigned use of filename. in any case initialize filename to

```
string filename = @"c:\somefile.txt";
```

and it should compile correctly.

Comment: That was not the problem. That was lost due to after posting my question 3 different people started editing my question contents and title. Acceptable effort but no. That content was simply lost due to edits.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
```

or

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(filePath));
```